# How to read ng-model data if I have used default selection option?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used the following code to bind my cost center information and also set the default.

**Controller**:
I have some logic to populate costCenterList.
say it has the following data:

```
$scope.costCenterList=[{ "costCenter": 111 }, { "costCenter": 112 }, { "costCenter": 113 }, { "costCenter": 114 }];

$scope.selected = $scope.costCenterList[0];
```

HTML:

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <div class="input-label">Cost-center</div>
    <select placeholder="Cost Center" ng-options="item.costCenter for item in costCenterList track by item.costCenter" ng-model="selected">
    </select>
</label>
```

Now, when I want to read the selected data in my controller using:

```
console.log("Selected costCenter:" + $scope.selected.costCenter);
```

Output:

```
Selected costCenter: 111
```

it prints the data which was presented to the form as default. It does present the data that I have selected using the form.

Any guidance here?

Comment: What happens when you run 'console.log("Selected costCenter:" + $scope.selected);'

Comment: So my costCenterList is a JSON object with content like: `code` {{
    "costCenter": 111
  },
  {
    "costCenter": 112
  },
  {
    "costCenter": 113
  },
  {
    "costCenter": 114
  }} `code`  ........................ So when I print the $scope.selected.costCenter it always prints 111.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?
       
          Cost-center

With controller:
  $scope.costCenterList=[{ "costCenter": 111 }, { "costCenter": 112 }, { "costCenter": 113 }, { "costCenter": 114 }];
  $scope.selected = $scope.costCenterList[0];

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
ng-options="item as item.costCenter for item in costCenterList"
```

Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/v8bb4wep/5/

I updated the fiddle with a button so you can see the value.

```
  <select placeholder="Cost Center" ng-options="item as item.costCenter for item in costCenterList" ng-model="selected" ng-init="selected=costCenterList[0]">
```

You can see this in an updated version of the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/v8bb4wep/6/

Comment: I tried your example. It works in the fiddle page. But in my application it still continues to print what was default selected i.e. 111.

Comment: Tough to solve an issue that you can't reproduce.  But I'd guess that the variable is being set in place that's being triggered repeatedly after the selection is made.  You could try setting the variable instead in an ng-init.  I'll add that to the answer....

Comment: oh - you changed the ng-options in your version, right?